# read a huge csv and create a dataframe

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv about 4000,0000 rows and 3 columns.I want to read into  python,and  create  a dataframe with these data. I always has memory error.

```
df = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in pd.read_csv(cmct_0430x.csv',chunksize=1000)])
```

I also tried  creat pandas DataFrame from generator,it still has memory error.

```
for line in open("cmct_0430x.csv"):
        yield line
```

my computer is win64,8G

how can I solve this problem? thank you very much.

Comment: as answeared, the size should be OK. 
and if the size is beyond the memory capacity - than it's impossible to store the data frame it self in memory.

I would guess there are some issues with the format of the file - for example, reading a file with a non default encoding (ascii or utf8) can cause similar error messages

Comment: Does it work ok with a smaller version of your file?  And even if you do manage to load the whole thing into a Dataframe, you might not have enough room to work with the frame.

Comment: it work with a smaller file.yes,I guess I may do not have enough room to work with it.

Comment: delimiter/seperator problems?

Comment: try `pd.read_csv('cmct_0430x.csv', nrows=1000000)`, and some other values for 1000000. See where it crashes

Answer (score 1):

`df = pd.read_csv('cmct_0430x.csv')`

40 million rows shouldn't be a problem.

please post your error message if this doesn't work

Comment: CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Answer (score 1):

You actually read the csv file with chunked mode, but merged them into one data-frame in RAM. So the problem still exists. You can divide your data into multiple frames, and work on them separately.

```
reader = pd.read_csv(file_name, chunksize=chunk_size, iterator=True)

while True:
    try:
        df = reader.get_chunk(chunk_size)
        # work on df
    except:
        break
    del df
```